# EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, facebook-social-plugins

I am using this plugin, it works well but a popup appears and asks me for my icloud password when I launch the application. Is there a way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've use this plugin a lot and it never does that to me, list all your cordova plugins with: `cordova plugins ls` and paste it here to check if you might have other plugin causing this problem and share the code you are using to trigger the plugin.